# How to fix "Сontains disallowed nested bundles" and "Contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'" Flutter with IOS share extension when deploy?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

I'm implementing the "Share" widget in a Flutter application using this guide (https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/ios/app-extensions). To achieve this, it's necessary to embed the Flutter framework (Flutter.xcframework from extension_safe directory) into the extension. I have no build issues, but when I try to submit to TestFlight, I encounter the following errors.

**Asset validation failed
Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Runner.app/Plugins/
share_extension.appex' contains
disallowed nested bundles. (ID: 25eb4da5-3868-40ab-bb64-d83b73d238c)**

**Asset validation failed
Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'Runner.app/Plugins/share_extension.appex' contains
disallowed file 'Frameworks'. (ID: e94a1815-1314-48f6-9b45-b6917b1fe627)**

I tried setting "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" to NO in the extension and YES in the project, but it didn't help.

The only thing that allowed deployment was setting the framework to "Do not embed," but this option is not suitable because it causes the share widget to stop appearing.